# Manually validating a JWT token in C#

Tags: c#, jwt, identityserver4

I am having some trouble **manually validating** a JWT token issued by Identity Server 4. Using the

ClientId: "CLIENT1"
ClientSecret: "123456"

The exception I keep getting is: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'

Is anyone able to advise me where I am going wrong.

```
    private static void ValidateJwt(string jwt, DiscoveryResponse disco)
    {        

        var parameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {

            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = disco.Issuer,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("123456")),               
            ValidAudience = "CLIENT1",
            //IssuerSigningKeys = keys,
            // ValidateAudience = true,
            // ValidateLifetime = true,
        };

        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        handler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        try
        {
            var user = handler.ValidateToken(jwt, parameters, out validatedToken);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var error = ex.Message;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(` can't be the right way to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out `ValidateJwt()` in this sample:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Clients/old/MvcManual/Controllers/HomeController.cs

The bit you're missing is loading the public key from the discovery document.

Comment: Its all about the public key.. not private a key. Thanks

Comment: I find I intermittently get this error, any reason why?

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: 'IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]', 
token: '[PII is hidden by default. Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'.'

Comment: Are you using a signing cert that's generated at runtime maybe?

Comment: Turns out that it was the load balancer.

Comment: "404: This is not the page you are looking for." says GitHub Obi-Wan Kenobe.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens Link updated, they must have deleted the branch.

Comment: @MarzSocks I am having a similar issue and I am trying to validate the JWT inside a service behind a load balancer. Can you share more details about your load balancer issue?

Comment: @peguerosdc Do you have details of the error? The most common cause of problems like this tends to be down to people using the default runtime generated signing keys which ofcourse change every time your IDS4 app is restarted and will be different on each machine.

Comment: The link is dead. Maybe paste in a part of the code in the answer?

Comment: @MarzSocks I am also having same problem when turn on Load Balancer. How to resolve this issue when load balancer is on?

Comment: @mackie broken link. Could you please advice how to resolve the problem when use load balancer?

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu such is the risk of linking to stuff in github :( The load balancer issue is likely due to the signing key not being shared between hosts. You must use the same certificate across all of your hosts.

Comment: @mackie Thanks for your reply. You meant `rsa` file. right? I am using the same `rsa` file across my two hosts machines. If not, could you please elaborate what actually you're talking about. Sorry, I am new to this.

Answer (score 9):

Try changing the length of your private key. Your private key is too small to be encoded I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

For manual verification, you could just use

```
static byte[] FromBase64Url(string base64Url)
        {
            string padded = base64Url.Length % 4 == 0
                ? base64Url : base64Url + "====".Substring(base64Url.Length % 4);
            string base64 = padded.Replace("_", "/")
                                  .Replace("-", "+");
            return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        }
```

This also answers @henk-holterman 's question

> Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( can't be the right way to do this.

Although realistically a better way to do this is via the OIDC discovery-endpoint
Auth0 has a good article about this using standard NuGet packages. Basically, you load everything needed from the discovery end-point.

```
IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>($"{auth0Domain}.well-known/openid-configuration", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdConfig = await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None);
TokenValidationParameters validationParameters =
    new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = auth0Domain,
        ValidAudiences = new[] { auth0Audience },
        IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConfig.SigningKeys
    };
SecurityToken validatedToken;
JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var user = handler.ValidateToken("eyJhbGciOi.....", validationParameters, out validatedToken);
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/manually-validating-rs256-jwt-dotnet/) Or their GitHub sample page about this [here](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-dotnet-validate-jwt/blob/master/IdentityModel-RS256/Program.cs)

In my case, I did not have a discovery endpoint. Just a JWKS endpoint.
So I opted to do this.

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ExpectedJwksResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "keys")]
        public List<JsonWebKey> Keys { get; set; }
    }

private static async Task<List<SecurityKey>> GetSecurityKeysAsync()
        {
            // Feel free to use HttpClient or whatever you want to call the endpoint.
            var client = new RestClient("<https://sample-jwks-endpoint.url>");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            var result = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<ExpectedJwksResponse>(request);
            if (result.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception("Wasnt 200 status code");
            }

            if (result.Data == null || result.Data.Keys == null || result.Data.Keys.Count == 0 )
            {
                throw new Exception("Couldnt parse any keys");
            }

            var keys = new List<SecurityKey>();
            foreach ( var key in result.Data.Keys )
            {
                keys.Add(key);
            }
            return keys;
        }

private async Task<bool> ValidateToken(token){
    TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidIssuer = "https://sample-issuer.com",
                ValidAudiences = new[] { "https://sample-audience/resource" },
                IssuerSigningKeys = await GetSecurityKeysAsync()
            };
    var user = null as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;
    SecurityToken validatedToken;
    try
    {
        user = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        Console.Write($"ErrorMessage: {e.Message}");
        return false;
    }
    var readToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
    var claims = readToken.Claims;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have specified:

```
IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret"))
```

but the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` could not match it with the key which [can be part of jwt header itself](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.4). Basically it means that your configuration has mismatch[es] with configuration of the real issuer. The error suggests that this relates to the signature keys.

Please, check the configuration of that issuer (if you can), find out missed parts, and try again.

You can use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) to debug your jwt online.

Answer (score 1):

IdentityServer signs the JWT using RS256. This means you need to use a public key to verify the JWT (you can get this from the discovery document).

The client id & client secret are client credentials used for requesting tokens. They have no part in validating them.

Comment: what is discovery document?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use SymmetricKey for JWT validation. Try looking your token in [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/) and if algorithm is"RS256" then SymmetricKey won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check when you create JWT token make sure that you added SigningCredentials.

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
  Constants.Audiance,Constants.Issuer,claims
   notBefore:DateTime.Now,
   expires:DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
   **signinCredential**
   );
```